# Facebook app invite for android

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-invite-friends

I am working on a new android app and I want to integrate the 'Invite Friends' from fb in order to invite them to use the app. I have added the required code in the app, I've also created the app in the developer portal from Facebook, but users are not getting the notification if I share it. 
I tried to also add the user in the settings -> tester users and yet no notification for them. 
Can someone help me on this? I over searched the internet, but I could find an answer on this.

Code used for opening the sharing dialog:

```
    private void InviteFriends()
    {
        if (AppInviteDialog.CanShow())
        {
            var content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                              .SetApplinkUrl(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_url))
                        //.SetPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                        .Build();
            AppInviteDialog.Show(this, (AppInviteContent)content);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
Alex

Comment: can you edit the question with your app invite code

Comment: What is the app invite code? And how will that help this? I know that I have an app URL created based on the app from Facebook developer console and app from play store.

Comment: Update question with the code you try to send    app invites

Comment: Note that I'm doing Xamarin Android and this is opening the sharing dialog, I can pick persons from the friend list, only that they don't receive the notification. Also I observed a strange behaviour, on the person that I've invited facebook, it appears an '1' in the left section near the games link menu, but when they click on it, there is nothing.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. I'm not sure but i think you need to invite friends to your app ( from what I read ). I will release my application in beta soon, so If you have no answer since this date I will try to not forget to come back here :)

Comment: Thank you! I am also thinking to submit it for review and maybe after will work. I'm out of ideas to try.

Comment: A precision , the feature not also work for my Windows Application

Comment: Hello, I released my WP app and my facebook page is public but i'm not able to see invitations :/